# Faenza microphone icon missing in the sound indicator

Tags: 11.10, icons, faenza

I just installed the faenza icon theme and the microphone icon under the sound indicator is missing and replaced by a placeholder. What can be the cause of this and how can I solve it?[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of this, never heard of before.

Comment: added screenshot

Comment: no issue in < 11.10 (sound rec is not integrated in sound menu). Perhaps it should be re-tagged with '11.10' tag

Comment: How did you install the theme?  Have you tried the other variants that come with it like Faenza-Dark, Darker, Ambiance etc?  Also can you post the output of `ls -al /usr/share/themes/Faenza*

Comment: *FIXED*: I also installed the gnome-shell package and seems to work now. Really strange though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(comment by OP solved issue)*

FIXED: I also installed the gnome-shell package and seems to work now. Really strange though. – nikita.utiu Jan 19 at 16:24